# How to convert pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy to dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I applied `groupby` on a `DataFrame` and after that it converted the `DataFrame` into `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` format.

How to convert `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` to regular `DataFrame` or how can I access individual columns from `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` datatype?

Comment: @Brad Solomon I checked out this but is there a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm trying to some operations on the dataframe after groupy, but I'm not able to figure out how can I access the data from "pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy" type of dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Let's say this is my dataframe:

```
my_df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
    {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},            
    {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
    {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
])
grouped_df = my_df.groupby('Firm')
# you can iterate through your new groupby object like this
for firm, group in grouped_df: 
    print(firm, '\n', group)

#Output 
A 
    Firm y1_bin y2_bin y3_bin
0    A   binA   binA   binB
1    A   binA   binA   binB

B 
     Firm y1_bin y2_bin y3_bin
2    B   binA   binA   binB
3    B   binA   binA   binB

# you can access individual values like this
for firm, group in grouped_df:
    for _, row in group.iterrows():
         print(row.firm, '\n', row.y1_bin)
#Output
A 
binA
A 
binA
B 
binA
B 
binA
```

More info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby